# Why I am not able to get stock price value in powershell?

Tags: powershell, web-scraping

I have written simple web scraping code in powershell.

```
$page = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://www.google.co.in/search?q=bank+of+india+share+price
$price = $page.ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName('span') |  Where-Object {$_.className -eq '_Rnb.fmob_pr.fac-l'}

$price.innerText
```

I went to https://www.google.co.in/search?q=bank+of+india+share+price right click on share price, inspect element, class name is **_Rnb fmob_pr fac-l**, but I see no output.

Please see screenshot I took from Google Chrome.

[image]

Comment: The box with stock information is probably only returned to browsers based on the user-agent string. I would grab the information [directly from google finance](https://www.google.com/finance?q=NSE:BANKINDIA) instead of through search

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Yes this worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: The proper stock information is returned, but the IHTMLDocument2 interface doesn't support multiple class names separated by spaces.

Comment: @PalleDue What could be solution?

Comment: + What Mathias wrote. Just because you are seeing a CSS class in the Chrome view source, it doesn't mean that Powershell is getting the same results. Powershell might be getting a mobile version of the page, and that definitely lacks the CSS class you are using for the parse. Does Powershell let you modify the User Agent? I would use something that let's you put whatever you want in the User Agent. (I use rebol or red for web-scraping-- these languages allow you to parse text or binary by writing grammars instead of regex, which is truly a blessing.)

Comment: I tried your example and did a few tests. ClassName for the element in question is blank, which I take to mean that the Html component used in Powershell does not understand multiple classes for an element. I found a few people who had had similar problems, some suggested using HtmlAgilityPack instead. I do not know HtmlAgilityPack, but you can find an example here: http://www.leeholmes.com/blog/2010/03/05/html-agility-pack-rocks-your-screen-scraping-world/.